# CodeIgniter shows error 404 instead views

Tags: codeigniter, view

I'm new in CodeIgniter,just installed locally an application and here here is my problem:
It shows error404 instead of view pages. When I look for "About Us", or "Contact US"...
Link generated is: http://localhost/webname/contact
Any idea how to solve it?
Thank you!

Comment: `http://localhost/webname/index.php/contact`

Comment: the same... not working

Comment: add code we can't guess your code

Comment: <div class="header
                    <?php
                        if(isset($homePage)):
                            echo 'homeHeader';
                        elseif(isset($aboutPage)):
                            echo aboutHeader';
                        elseif(isset($contactPage)):
                            echo 'contactHeader';
                        else:
                            echo 'homeHeader';
                        endif; ?>">
</div>
this is the code for header on the menu

Comment: add In your question. Add controller and View as well

Comment: I solved the problem. The page name, or view name, was actually coming from database :) 
Thank you!